# Can we use 2 or more SoftwareSerial in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, software-serial

So I have a project that need *ESP-01 (ESP8266)* and *Fingerprint Sensor (FM10A)*, both of it would be connected to Arduino UNO. Both of the component need to communicate from SoftwareSerial. **For some project-related reason I can't use the hardware-serial.**

The programs works like this:

1. The fingerprint sensor is going to capture a fingerprint and give it an ID (String)
2. The ID is going to be sent to firebase database using ESP-01

Is it possible to make them work using 2 SoftwareSerial?

[ESP-01 Pins](https://components101.com/wireless/esp8266-pinout-configuration-features-datasheet) | [Fingerprint Sensor FM10A Pins](https://i1.wp.com/www.nyebarilmu.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Pinout-Sensor-Fingerprint-FPM10A.png?resize=446%2C509&ssl=1)

Any helpful response would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The  ESP-01 (ESP8266)is only a WiFi module with 2 gpios available.
It should be used together with a micro-controller board and not stand alone.
Better is to get a micro-controller board like esp32.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Arduino UNO as microcontroller board. Is it possible to use 2 SoftwareSerial?

Comment: SoftwareSerial library has the following known limitations:

    It cannot transmit and receive data at the same time.
    If using multiple software serial ports, only one can receive data at a time.   

If your project requires simultaneous data flows, see Paul Stoffregen's AltSoftSerial library.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not a good answer: I am not sure.

You can certainly use 2 `SoftwareSerial` and make use of them with no problem but that library comes with limitations [as per the official documentation](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/software-serial)

Quoting from what I've linked:

> SoftwareSerial library has the following known limitations:
>
> - It cannot transmit and receive data at the same time.
> - If using multiple software serial ports, only one can receive data at a time.
> - Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 boards support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 10, 11, 12, 13,
>   14, 15, 50, 51, 52, 53, A8 (62), A9 (63), A10 (64), A11 (65), A12
>   (66), A13 (67), A14 (68), A15 (69).
> - Not all pins on the Leonardo and
>   Micro boards support change interrupts, so only the following can be
>   used for RX: 8, 9, 10, 11, 14 (MISO), 15 (SCK), 16 (MOSI).
> - On Arduino or Genuino 101 boards the current maximum RX speed is 57600bps.
> - On Arduino or Genuino 101 boards RX doesn't work on digital pin 13.
> - If your project requires simultaneous data flows, see Paul
>   Stoffregen's [AltSoftSerial](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html) library.

Of course this library was built for Arduino and you might have to deal with other stuff if you're planning on to program the ESP8266.

I also remember having to deal with extra noise when using the `SoftwareSerial` at some higher baud-rates. So keep that in mind!